# Symmetric matrix decomposition with orthonormal basis of non-eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I like to understand the following transformation found in documentation for deriving [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter).

**Abstract Formulation**: Given 2 symmetric matrices $A$ ,$B$ $\in$  $\mathbb R^{3,3}$ with $A \ne B$ and a set of orthonormal Eigenvectors ($u_1$, $u_2$, $u_3$) from some other matrix $B$ (not $A$!). Because the matrices are symmetric it is clear that $B$ can be decomposed to $B = U\Lambda U^t$. 
Now there is stated that A can be written as:

$A$ = ($u_1^t$A$u_1$)$u_1$$u_1^t$ + ($u_2^t$A$u_2$)$u_2$$u_2^t$ + ($u_3^t$A$u_3$)$u_3$$u_3^t$
i.e. with the "foreign" Eigenvectors.

**Concrete Situation**: In the original equation the above mentioned $A$ is defined as $H_kP_k^-H_k^t$ + $R_a$, where $P^-$ is the a priori estimation error covariance and $R_a$ is the sensor noise error covariance matrix. $H_k$ has 3x9 dimension and contains some "more abstract" content with rotation matrix of a quaternion multiplied with cross product operator of gravity vector (0,0,g). As far as I can see, the term ($H_kP_k^-H_k^t$ + $R_a$) does not lead to a diagonal matrix and this seems to be irrelevant. What I called $B$ is actually the signal's overall error error covariance named $U_k$

From original paper:

[image: From paper]

Because $U_k$ covariance matrix cannot be obtained at this point in time (a priori estimation), it is approximated by the average of the last M steps i.e. from k-M to k-1. The signal itself might be fluctuating considerably because sometimes there is external acceleration at other times there isn't thus sensor noise is the only thing be measured.

**Assumption** (thanks to Calle's and joriki's comments): The eigendecomposition of $U_k$ is related to [PCA Principal component analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_components_analysis) (an easier one [here](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/cosc453/student_tutorials/principal_components.pdf)). The most interesting cases are all those measurements with strong accelerations i.e. $U_k$ is much greater than the remaining term. So this decomposition of the 2nd term transforms it (approximatively?) towards the direction of the strongest signal. Thus $\lambda - \mu$ helps to detect these situations respectively distinguish them from phases with no signal aside from noise.

- Does this explanation makes sense?
- Can this procedure of approximating with "wrong" eigenvectors and -values be applied and compares like with like?
- What is the name of this [matrix
  decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition) taking not their
  own eigenvectors?
- What is about the error?

Thanks for helping

Kay

PS: Title changed from "Symmetric matrix multiplied with kind of orthonormal basis"

Comment: Seems a bit odd. If $A$ could be written this way, $Au_1 = (u_1^T A u_1) u_1$, so $u_1$ should be an eigenvector of $A$ as well. Are you sure there aren't more conditions and the equation is correct?

Comment: Is $B$ related to $A$ in any way?

Comment: AFAIK that's all about it but I updated the question to get things more clear.

Comment: I think you need to go back to the definition of $U_k$.

Comment: $U_k$ is an error covariance matrix as well that cannot be obtained at this point in time. So it is approximated by the average of the last M steps i.e. from k-M to k-1.

Comment: This seems to be a mistake in the book. As Calle wrote, equation (33) only holds if the $u_i$ are eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: By the way, it wouldn't help if $A$ were diagonal (unless $B$ is diagonal).

Comment: I think my description was a little bit confusing after the update: $B = U_k$ while $A = H_kP_k^-H_k^t + R_a$. Now the $R_a$ part of A is diagonal but $H_kP_k^-H_k^t$ not. I will edit the question to clear things up.

Comment: @Kay: I thought your description was clear enough; $A$ and $B$ in my comments referred to just those matrices. My comment about $A$ being diagonal not helping was in reference to your statement that "this product $(H_kP_k^-H_k^t+R_a)$ does not lead to a diagonal matrix".

Comment: @moderators: Maybe PCA or more general multivariate-analysis would be a candidate for new tag.

Comment: I tried to do all the multiplications given in the abstract formulation but this leads to exploding equations. I am thinking about some empiric approach using Octave/Matlab to get an idea of what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing a matrix $A$ in terms of a basis that does not diagonalize the matrix $A$ is possible, but it requires a full expansion of all terms, not just the diagonal terms. (If the basis diagonalizes $A$ then all off diagonal terms would be zero).

If $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix and you write $ A = U U^{-1} A UU^{-1}$ with
$$U = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{u}_1 & \mathbf{u}_2 & \mathbf{u}_3\end{bmatrix}$$
then you have the sum along all pairs $ij$ (not just for $i=j$)
$$ A = \sum_{ij}\mathbf{u}_i ( \mathbf{u}_i^\top A \mathbf{u}_j)\mathbf{u}_j^\top$$

I can not tell you why the off diagonal terms were ignored, perhaps it is by design or perhaps by mistake.

Here is the full expansion:

\begin{align}
  U^{-1}AU &=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{u}_1^\top  \\ \mathbf{u}_2^\top  \\ \mathbf{u}_3^\top \end{bmatrix}  A\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{u}_1 & \mathbf{u}_2 & \mathbf{u}_3\end{bmatrix} \\
  &=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{u}_1^\top A \\ \mathbf{u}_2^\top A \\ \mathbf{u}_3^\top A\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{u}_1 & \mathbf{u}_2 & \mathbf{u}_3\end{bmatrix} \\
  &= \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{u}_1^\top A \mathbf{u}_1  & \mathbf{u}_1^\top A \mathbf{u}_2 & \mathbf{u}_1^\top A \mathbf{u}_3 \\ \mathbf{u}_2^\top A \mathbf{u}_1  & \mathbf{u}_2^\top A \mathbf{u}_2 & \mathbf{u}_2^\top A \mathbf{u}_3 \\\mathbf{u}_3^\top A \mathbf{u}_1  & \mathbf{u}_3^\top A \mathbf{u}_3 & \mathbf{u}_3^\top A \mathbf{u}_3 \\\end{bmatrix} \\
  UU^{-1}AUU^{-1} &=  \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{u}_1 & \mathbf{u}_2 & \mathbf{u}_3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{u}_1^\top A \mathbf{u}_1  & \mathbf{u}_1^\top A \mathbf{u}_2 & \mathbf{u}_1^\top A \mathbf{u}_3 \\ \mathbf{u}_2^\top A \mathbf{u}_1  & \mathbf{u}_2^\top A \mathbf{u}_2 & \mathbf{u}_2^\top A \mathbf{u}_3 \\\mathbf{u}_3^\top A \mathbf{u}_1  & \mathbf{u}_3^\top A \mathbf{u}_2 & \mathbf{u}_3^\top A \mathbf{u}_3 \\\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{u}_1^\top \\ 
 \mathbf{u}_2^\top \\ \mathbf{u}_3^\top\end{bmatrix} \\ \hphantom{A} \\
   A &=  \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{u}_1 & \mathbf{u}_2 & \mathbf{u}_3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{u}_1^\top A \mathbf{u}_1 \mathbf{u}_1^\top + \mathbf{u}_1^\top A \mathbf{u}_2 \mathbf{u}_2^\top + \mathbf{u}_1^\top A \mathbf{u}_3\mathbf{u}_3^\top \\ \mathbf{u}_2^\top A \mathbf{u}_1\mathbf{u}_1^\top  + \mathbf{u}_2^\top A \mathbf{u}_2\mathbf{u}_2^\top  + \mathbf{u}_2^\top A \mathbf{u}_3\mathbf{u}_3^\top \\\mathbf{u}_3^\top A \mathbf{u}_1\mathbf{u}_1^\top  + \mathbf{u}_3^\top A \mathbf{u}_2\mathbf{u}_2^\top + \mathbf{u}_3^\top A \mathbf{u}_3\mathbf{u}_3^\top \\\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \sum_{ij}\mathbf{u}_i ( \mathbf{u}_i^\top A \mathbf{u}_j)\mathbf{u}_j^\top
\end{align}